# Ampscript BuildRowsetFromString() fails on single item

Tags: exacttarget, ampscript

I've been tasked with an ExactTarget task, which uses Ampscript. Trying to learn on the go here. See code snippet below:

```
%%[
    Var @testString, @testOutput
    Set @testString = Qwerty
    Set @testOutput = BuildRowsetFromString(@testString,"~")
]%%

TestOutput:%%= v(@testOutput) =%%
```

The code works if the `testString` contains a `~`, but when there is no `~` character in the string, the ouput is blank. Is this correct by design? Do I need to add a conditional to check for the presence of the `~` character?

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [ampscript](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the expected behavior. The **BuildRowsetFromString()** function alone isn't going to return any value when displayed, you're going to need to use **Row()** and **Field()** in order to pull the value out.

Using your example:

```
%%[
    Var @testString, @testOutput

    Set @testString = "Qwerty"
    Set @testOutput = BuildRowsetFromString(@testString,"~")

]%%

RowCount: %%=RowCount(@testOutput)=%%
TestOutput: %%=v(@testOutput)=%%
```

The **RowCount()** function returns a value of 1, essentially saying it knows there's at least one 'row' in there. To display that one value, you'll need to wrap that value with **Field()** and **Row()**:

```
TestOutput: %%=Field(Row(@testOutput,1),1)=%%
```

If you want to display other values in the string, say you were passing "Qwerty~Second~Third", you'll need to either change the number at the **Row()** function or perform a loop.

**References**

[Using Loops](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/getting_started_with_ampscript/ampscript_401/)

[BuildRowsetFromString() Function](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/content/BuildRowSetFromString.html)

Comment: This was most helpful. Thank-you.